# AWS Secrets and Parameters Lambda Extension throw not ready to serve traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-extensions

I'm trying to use AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension. From the documentation, looks straightforward, just send GET request to localhost:2773 and attach header AWS session token. I tried that, but it gave me `not ready to serve traffic, please wait`.

The weird thing is above that I can already see that the server is actually ready to serve traffic `[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/03/03 08:05:50 INFO ready to serve traffic`.

My code is in Golang:

```
// Using Lambda Extensions to get SSM Parameters and Secrets Manager env vars
func LoadEnvVarsFromLambdaExtension() {
    paramsSecretsExtensionHttpPort := utils.GetEnv("PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_HTTP_PORT", "2773")
    awsSessionToken := utils.GetEnv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN", "")

    ssmParamsUrl := "http://localhost:" + paramsSecretsExtensionHttpPort + "/systemsmanager/parameters/get?name="
    urlWithDecryption := "&withDecryption=true"
    secretsUrl := "http://localhost:" + paramsSecretsExtensionHttpPort + "/secretsmanager/get?secretId="

    internalApiTokenSSMPath := utils.GetEnv("INTERNAL_API_TOKEN", "")
    jwtSecretSSMPath := utils.GetEnv("JWT_SECRET", "")
    redisSecretPath := utils.GetEnv("REDIS_SECRETS_ARN", "")

    internalApiTokenGetUrl := ssmParamsUrl + internalApiTokenSSMPath + urlWithDecryption
    jwtSecretGetUrl := ssmParamsUrl + jwtSecretSSMPath + urlWithDecryption
    redisGetUrl := secretsUrl + redisSecretPath

    EnvSettings.InternalAPIToken, _ = httpGet(internalApiTokenGetUrl, awsSessionToken)
    EnvSettings.JwtSecret, _ = httpGet(jwtSecretGetUrl, awsSessionToken)
    EnvSettings.RedisSecret, _ = httpGet(redisGetUrl, awsSessionToken)
}


// http GET request with headers
func httpGet(url string, awsSessionToken string) (string, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(errors.Wrap(err, "Error creating request"))
    }

    req.Header.Set("X-Aws-Parameters-Secrets-Token", awsSessionToken)

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(errors.Wrap(err, "Error sending request"))
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(errors.Wrap(err, "Error reading body"))
    }
    
    return string(body), nil
}
```

And I kinda just run it in main function, set it up first

```
func main() {
    lambdaUtils.LoadEnvVarsFromLambdaExtension()
    lambda.Start(HandleRequestTest)
}

func HandleRequestTest(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    fmt.Println(lambdaUtils.EnvSettings.InternalAPIToken)
    fmt.Println(lambdaUtils.EnvSettings.JwtSecret)
    fmt.Println(lambdaUtils.EnvSettings.RedisSecret)

    return lambdaUtils.EnvSettings.RedisSecret, nil
}
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind. I'm just being silly that the invocation is before the lambda handler, so the lambda extension obviously not ready when it is tried to be loaded.

It should be:

```
func HandleRequestTest(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    lambdaUtils.LoadEnvVarsFromLambdaExtension()
    fmt.Println(lambdaUtils.EnvSettings.InternalAPIToken)
    fmt.Println(lambdaUtils.EnvSettings.JwtSecret)
    fmt.Println(lambdaUtils.EnvSettings.RedisSecret)

    return lambdaUtils.EnvSettings.RedisSecret, nil
}
```

But actually, this does not solve my problem in getting the params and secret manager since my lambda is inside VPC, which cannot get internet access unless provision a NAT Gateway.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I saw tutorials on Medium which used the extension outside the handler which failed in my case...